# How can I identify this if condition to be False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to identify if the string is at least 2 characters or else, they need to input the string again. The code doesn't work, what did I do wrong?

For example, I type "jason@yahoo.c":

```
email_address = input('Enter your email address: ')

dns_label = email_address.split('.')
local = dns_label[0]
dns = dns_label[1]

if not len(local)>=2 and len(dns)>=2:
    email_address = input('''Your email address is incorrect.\n Please type your email address again: ''')
else:
    print(email_address,'is valid')
```

After the dot it only has 1 character, so it will ask the user again for the input.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `not` operator has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) over `and`, therefore you must put the expression into brackets:

```
if not (len(local) >= 2 and len(dns) >= 2):
```

or better, remove the `not` altogether to make it more readable:

```
if len(local) < 2 or len(dns) < 2:
```

Edit: That being said, an `if` clause is not sufficient for input validation as it will only check the entry once. What if the user types an incorrect email address the second time too? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you, the code is running after I changed into while loops. Very helpful